# Counting how many rows LOAD DATA INFILE has inserted

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a text file that has names in the following format,

```
firstname:lastname
```

Here is the query I am running,

```
$this->db->query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'names.txt' INTO TABLE names FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' (firstname, lastname)");
```

How can I count how many rows this inserted?

Comment: try this function mysql_affected_rows()

Answer (score 2):

from [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

> When the LOAD DATA INFILE statement
>   finishes, it returns an information
>   string in the following format:
>
> ```
> Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```
>
> If you are using the C API, you can
>   get information about the statement by
>   calling the mysql_info() function.

so try use [mysql_info()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-info.php)

like :

```
 $info_str = mysql_info($$link);
    if (ereg("Records: ([0-9]*)", $info_str, $count) == false) {
        ereg("Rows matched: ([0-9]*)", $info_str, $count);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run following query:

```
 SELECT ROW_COUNT()
```

From [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)

`ROW_COUNT()` returns a value as follows:

- DDL statements: 0. This applies to statements such as `CREATE TABLE` or `DROP TABLE`.
- DML statements other than `SELECT`: The number of affected rows. This applies to statements such as `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` (as before), but now also to statements such as `ALTER TABLE` and `LOAD DATA`.
- `SELECT`: -1 if the statement returns a result set, or the number of rows “affected” if it does not. For example, for `SELECT * FROM t1`, ROW_COUNT() returns -1.
- For `SELECT * FROM t1 INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'`, `ROW_COUNT()` returns the number of rows written to the file.